# Truncated tweets texts

Tags: import, web-access, social-media

I use the Twitter command

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]
listTws = twitter["TweetSearch", "Query" -> "Trump", MaxItems -> 10];
```

For example, the text of the first tweet is

```
listTws[[1]]["Text"]
```

whose output is

```
"RT @BreitbartNews: \"Let\[CloseCurlyQuote]s turn a negative into a     
positive... I want them to say, \[OpenCurlyQuote]Look, we are not
profiting off the deaths of children. We..."
```

The tweet is truncated. If I look at the original tweet https://twitter.com/BreitbartNews/status/966449304192811008, the original phrase is  completed.

*Who can I extract the whole sentence??*

**UPDATE**I have noticed that the truncated tweets' length is 140, whereas the total length is 280. This may be related to the new feature of twitter. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: As you say in your update, this is likely related to the new feature. On Stackoverflow one can find out that they changed the API and that a special option has to be given to avoid the truncation. This probably means that WRI has to update the source code of Mathematica. I think it would be good to send a bug report to make sure that they are aware of it.